# Generate a equinox environment and config by script (Ant or something) of deployed OSGI bundles

Tags: maven, osgi, equinox, tycho

I am searching for a way to generate a run able equinox configuration of deployed OSGI bundles.

A build server deploys our OSGI bundles via maven and tycho-plugin and placed them in the m2 directory.
Now, the next step is to collect the bundles from the deployment directory and put them together in a equinox configuration and start up the container.

Collect the bundles and configure the equinox container manually is not the way I prefer so now I looking for a way to do this automatically via script.

There are solutions like ANT script?

Hoping for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is generate an `config.ini` file which you can put in your `configuration/` directory. The `osgi.bundles` entry in there allows you to specify what bundles to install and start, e.g.:

`config.ini` content:

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.osgi.services@start, ../mydirectory/mybundle.jar@start
```

You may need to specify the configuration directory when launching equinox to ensure the `config.ini` is picked up, e.g.

```
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106.jar -configuration configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a "product" (i.e. a fully self-contained OSGi runtime).

See the tycho docs  in general [1] and esp. exercise 5 of the tycho tutorial [2] with solution [3]

[1] http://eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php

[2] http://eclipsecon.org/sessions/building-eclipse-plugins-and-rcp-applications-tycho

[3] https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/tree/master/exercises/Exercise_06_Solution

Comment: use org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:materialize-products to materialize eclipse product based on features/plugins configuration (.product file)

Comment: But now i have an new problem, the build fails by adding a thrift bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/sarod/equinox-config-builder to easily generate a config.ini from a plugins directory.